# Screens go blank and windows move around

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have a 2-monitor Windows7 PC. A few times a day, both screens go black for about a second. When they come back, I frequently find all my windows have been moved onto my primary monitor, maximised windows have been un-maximised, etc.

It's a bit like a monitor has been unplugged briefly but both go blank and I have double-checked all the VGA and power cables are properly plugged in.

I wonder if it could be a driver issue, or a hardware fault, but I don't really know where to start since I can't find a good Google search query, and I don't have spare graphics cards or monitors.

Any suggestions on where to look for more information or what to try are very welcome.

Comment: have you tried to update the driver?  Also check the gfx card isn't loose in the case. What is make and model of the card?

Comment: Do you have any screen saver clicking on? It could be a fault with the card or even a power issue.

Comment: @DaveRook no screensaver, this happens while I'm using the computer.

Comment: The only other thing it might be (very small chance): Can you check your Task Scheduler to make sure there are no programs trying to run which are causing this.

Comment: When a screen is temporarily unplugged (possibly due to a faulty connection), it is not uncommon for both screens to go blank due to the reinitialization of the Windows Desktop. In case your graphics driver would have crashed, Windows would usually notify you about that fact through an information bubble. If that is not the case, I would suspect some sort of hardware defect. Check your connections first, replacing cables would probably be the next, least expensive step.